# Is there another way to make animated paths or polygons without using SMIL

Tags: svg, smil

> SMIL is deprecated and not going to work on chrome anymore

I just started learning how to do animated svg's and I stumbled upon this statement. I don't know if it's true (and I hope it's wrong).

**edit :** It is indeed true, sadly.

My question now is : Is there another way to make animated paths or polygons without using SMIL? For example, can I play with the "d" attribute of a path using something that's not SMIL?

I hope some of you guys has an answer, I really like the possibilities in terms of animations that svg has.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it'll be more understandable now!

Comment: There are http://greensock.com/ with its GSAP API and also http://snapsvg.io/

Comment: The Blink (Chrome) team are only deprecating it.  AFAIK there are no plans to remove it completely. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM%5B1-25%5D

Comment: To [quote RobertLongson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420323/how-to-animate-path-shape-without-using-smil/33428336#comment-54649080) on a [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420323/how-to-animate-path-shape-without-using-smil) : "SMIL has great browser support. Via http://leunen.me/fakesmile it works on pretty much anything that supports SVG and javascript no matter whether Chrome deprecates it or not. Chrome actually has a different non-native SMIL plugin: http://github.com/ericwilligers/svg-animation available so there's plenty of reasons to stick with SMIL

Comment: Thanks a lot, it gives me some hope. But it means i'm going to learn a new syntax as well! No matter. Another question, will it still work with these plugins if SMIL is completely removed from browsers?

Comment: @ken, these plugins were meant to make SMIL work where it was never implemented (IE) so yes, if the UA does support svg rendering, svg DOM manipulation and javascript, thses libraries will still work. (I guess it will take some time before chrome also deprecates javascript ;-/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel better now!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should note that SMIL has only been deprecated  since [chrome 45 and Opera 32](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5371475380928512). This means that there is a warning in the console but the features still works now (dec 2015).

[canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil) states :

> As of Chrome 45 & Opera 32 SMIL is deprecated and usage will result in a warning in the console. Support is expected to be dropped in some future version.

For more info about this, you can also check this thread: [Intent to deprecate SMIL](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/blink-dev/smil/blink-dev/5o0yiO440LM/59rZqirUQNwJ)

---

An alternative to morphing an SVG path with SMIL is to use [snap.svg](http://snapsvg.io/) here is an example :

```js
var s = Snap().attr({viewBox: '0 0 100 150'});

s.path('M50 10 C50 10, 10 50, 50 50 C50 50, 10 10, 50 10z')
 .animate({ d: "M50 10 C90 10, 10 90, 50 90 C90 90, 10 10, 50 10z" }, 2000, mina.elastic);
```

```css
svg {width: 30%;height: auto;stroke-width: 1;stroke: #000;fill: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg.js"></script>
```

Note that you can also use [greensock](https://greensock.com/) with the [morphSVG plugin](http://greensock.com/morphSVG).